# peripheral.DiscoverCharacteristic Method in Core Bluetooth - Xamarin

Tags: ios, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, xamarin, core-bluetooth

I am creating a Xamarin.Ios Bluetooth app and my question is following:

Is there any way to discover characteristics of all services in the peripheral at once. I mean to say if i have three services (a,b,c) and i call peripheral.discoverCharacteristic(a); 
three time a,b,c and then receive the characteristic call back in discover characteristic  of all discovered characteristics of all services. I know it can do the call back everytime when i call peripheral.discovercharacteristic() but i need to have discover all characteristic from all service in place before i do anything. This is my use requirement. 
Please help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible directly.

You will have to use one DiscoverCharacteristic call for every single service, then process the results using custom app logic.

Answer (score 0):

When I've discovered the services of a CBPeripheral, I call `discoverCharacteristics` once with *all* the characteristics that I'm looking for;

```
for (CBService *service in peripheral.services)
{
    DDLogInfo(@"Kicking discovery of characteristics for servive %@", service);
    [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_A],
                                          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_B],
                                          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_C],
                                          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_D]]
                             forService:service];
}
```

Then, in the `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:error:`, I loop through the discovered results and store references to the characteristics that I'll need later on, and that's that.

```
for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
{
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_A]])
        self.currentCharacteristicA = characteristic;
    else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_B]])
        self.currentCharacteristicB = characteristic;
    else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_C]])
        self.currentCharacteristicC = characteristic;
    else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_D]])
        self.currentCharacteristicD = characteristic;
}
```

And, obviously, cleanup the self.currentCharacteristic* nicely when disconnected.

Comment: I guess the Xamarin interfaces are stricter than CoreBluetooth and it is not possible to batch the discovery requests.

Comment: So true -- and I just now realized that the question was for Xamarin, not native iOS. My bad. Ignore me!

Comment: Hi Markus, I am trying now in right way. As I have three discovered services a,b,c but i am having hard time calling peripheral.discovercharacteristic method one by one. At first, when i call peripheral.discovercharacteristic(for service - a) then i got the call back in discovercharacteristic method but after this when i try to discover characteristic for second service( b),it did not do the call back,

Comment: You can batch them, just use CBPeripheral.DiscoverCharacteristics (new CBUUID [] { myUid1, myUid2, myUid3 });   See API here: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.CBPeripheral.DiscoverCharacteristics(MonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.CBUUID%5b%5d%2cMonoTouch.CoreBluetooth.CBService)

Comment: It only gives me the discovered characteristics of first service in the for loop and for rest of the services there characteristics are null.

Comment: This is what i do=>                  for(int i=0; i<peripheral.services.length;i++)
{
CBService service=peripheral.services[i];

Peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(new CBUUID[]{a,b,c},service);

}

After this, I  receive the call back response in  cbperipheral delegate  DiscoverCharacteristic method.

Public void override DiscoverCharacteristic(CBPeripheral peripheral, CBService service, NSError error)
{
// Here I receive the characteristic  of only single service but I am discovering for all services in the above for loop that is the issue.
}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, In xamarin it only works with discovering for characteristic for a service ,not like a batch discovery. I will need to discover characteristics for a given service one by one and process it  and discover again for next service as Etan explained in the first answer. It works for me and will think of changing my use case requirements accordingly. Thanks Everyone for sharing your thoughts.